# Special merging in R

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a data frame with lots of rows and columns, but for this particular exercise I only need two columns for that data frame. For example, I have this:

```
    ID Amount
  1  7    100
  2  6    495
  3 85    550
  4 64    600
  5  3    150
```

And I have another data frame which also have lots of rows and columns but I only need three columns:

```
  ID Perc Type
1  7 0.05    A
2  6 0.50    A
3 85 0.75    A
4  7 0.90    B
5 64 0.30    C
6  3 0.50    A
7 64 0.40    A
```

What I need to do is merge the two data frames by ID, but have an extra column that tells me the percentage of each one, and to put zero if not found, like this:

```
  ID Amount    A   B   C
1  7    100 0.05 0.9 0.0
2  6    495 0.50 0.0 0.0
3 85    550 0.75 0.0 0.0
4 64    600 0.40 0.0 0.3
5  3    150 0.50 0.0 0.0
```

Maybe it is not about merging exactly, but that is what only comes to my mind.

Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to transform the second data frame from long to wide (see package reshape2 for ease of use) and then merge its result to the first one.

Do the following:

```
library(reshape2)

# Transform from long to wide
df2_wide = dcast(df2, ID ~ Type, value.var = "Perc")

# Set NAs to 0
df2_wide[is.na(df2_wide)] = 0

# Merge both data frames
df3 = merge(df1,df2_wide)
```

Where `df2` is your second data frame and `df1` the first one.

Result:

```
  ID Amount    A   B   C
1  3    150 0.50 0.0 0.0
2  6    495 0.50 0.0 0.0
3  7    100 0.05 0.9 0.0
4 64    600 0.40 0.0 0.3
5 85    550 0.75 0.0 0.0
```

Comment: Using base R's `reshape` instead of `dcast` you'd do `reshape(df2, idvar="ID", direction="wide", timevar="Type")`.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the `tidyr` and `dplyr` packages

```
df1<-structure(list(ID = c(7L, 6L, 85L, 64L, 3L), Amount = c(100L,  495L, 550L, 600L, 150L)), 
          .Names = c("ID", "Amount"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"))

df2<-structure(list(ID = c(7L, 6L, 85L, 7L, 64L, 3L, 64L),  Perc = c(0.05,  0.5, 0.75, 0.9, 0.3, 0.5, 0.4), 
             Type = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L,  2L, 3L, 1L, 1L), 
             .Label = c("A", "B", "C"), class = "factor")), 
             .Names = c("ID", "Perc", "Type"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c("1", "2",  "3", "4", "5", "6", "7"))

library(tidyr)
#go from long to wide format
df2w<-spread(df2, Type, Perc, fill=0)

library(dplyr)
#merge the 2 data frames together
final answer<-left_join(df2w, df1, by="ID")
```